# Getting the original cause of a JschException

Tags: java, exception, ssh, jsch

I need to do some handling for a JschException. It looks like "JschException" is thrown regardless of what the specific cause of the exception was (ie. SocketTimeoutException, UnknownHostKey, or AuthFail). What's the best way for me to go about determining the original specific cause? Is my only option to parse the `e.getMessage()` String?

Here is the basic structure.

```
try {
    session = jSch.getSession(getUsername(), host);
    session.setUserInfo(user);
    session.connect();
} catch (JSchException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    // Here I need to identify the cause and handle accordingly.
}
```

As an example here is the top trace for a timeout and a authentication failure respectively.

`com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out`

`com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail`

If it matters, I want to initiate a retry of the try block for authentication errors, and fail out for timeouts errors.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, JSch throws exceptions is a way that makes it impossible to find the root cause (except for parsing the exception message).

JSch is full of code like this:

```
catch(Exception e) {
  ...
  throw new JSchException("Session.connect: "+e);
}
```